# Bridging multiple edges at a time

Tags: modeling, edges

I try to create a face between two edges, but it always gets a strange looking result.
I worked for years with another cad application called "Vector". In this App if you select edges, the software orders the edges from 0 to n by selection and shows the order. Blender doesn't do this, but I found an extension called "space_view3d_index_visualiser_bmesh.py", no it works fine.

The internal blender order seems quite confused, so I reordered it with "Sort Mesh Elements".

[image: new order works]

After pressing <kbd>F</kbd> to create a face between the edges, this is the result:

[image: strange face after "f"]

I think this is an edge order problem. If I Select each corresponding edge separately (0-1, <kbd>F</kbd>, 2-3 <kbd>F</kbd> .... etc) it works fine, but this is boring work with large Objects. Is there any solution?

Comment: ctrl+E then "bridge edge loops" (before you create the face)

Answer (score 7):

<kbd>F</kbd> in blender creates one face. So when you have many edges selected at once you are creating one large Ngon, not what you want to do.

You are looking for blender's [bridge edge loops](https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/meshes/editing/edges.html#bridge-edge-loops) tool. In edit mode from the 3D view header *Mesh* > *Edges* > *Bridge Edge Loops*. Or quicker through keyboard shortcuts <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> <kbd>L</kbd>.

After running the bridge edge loops tool you will get more options in the operator part of the tool shelf.
[image: bridge edge loops settings]

One of the most important is the *Twist*, if you get edges that are crossing over each other like in the image below, then just change the number till the offset is correct. 
[image: bridge error]

Answer (score 4):

The simplest solution for you would to just use the F key.  Blender will automatically bridge the edges if you first select the first two vertices of the edges and press F.  This will just create a line in between the vertices.  But if you keep pressing F, Blender will automatically detect which edges to fill next. Blender does the hard work for you.

Answer (score 2):

Because CAD system use different approach to modeling. It's like *"curve"s* vs *"mesh"* in Blender or *"splines"* vs *"mesh"* in 3Ds.

For cases like this usually work *"Grid fill"*.

In edit mode press: "CTRL + F" > "G"

You can adjust properties in *Tool panel* on left.

BTW: does not matter on vertex order.